# need to query max number from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have table like this

```
test_id  test_name
1        abc
2        def
3        ghi
we       jkl
```

I need to query the maximum number from this table.i.e only number (3)

Comment: what is `we` in test_id... a typo mistake ??

Comment: maximum number from `all columns` in your table or maximum number from `test_id`? And is `test_id` = varchar?

Comment: Test_id column  is varchar2(100) and in DB column test_id have numbers and text .. I need query to fetch max. number from test_id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test to check if a value in a column is a number is `ISNUMERIC(column_name)`. What you want is the maximum `test_id` with a numeric value.
Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(test_id)
FROM table
WHERE ISNUMERIC(test_id) = 1
```

EDIT: Since mysql doesn't have a ISNUMERIC function, you can use REGEXP.

```
WHERE test_id REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: we need to declare the function isnumeric in database right?

Comment: i tried this query and its working,
select max(CAST((substring(PARTY_ID,1)) AS DECIMAL(5,0)))  from PARTY

Comment: `isnumeric` is a built-in function. It's already in a lot of databases. ;)

Comment: I dont have this function in my DB. Can u pls share me the function :) ;)

Comment: Updated answer to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(test_id*1) as max_id
from your_table
```

or to get the complete record

```
select *
from your_table
order by test_id * 1 desc
limit 1
```

Comment: if we give select max(test_id) as max_id
from your_table, it will give output as we.

I need output as 3